# Custom Image map with Multiple polygon - Added a Map Icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a Image Map - with 20 clickable Marker Points made using polygons.

I want to add a Marker Icon Center to each Polygon Which If possible changes color when Active(clicked) can use SVG or .png for Pin.

When clicked they add #1,#2 etc to URL - used for populating a TEXT area on page with contact Info.

Each Area is added to the map using a foreach statement.

tried using a "symbol" but it can't get to center within each polygon.

```
<svg id="svgmap<?= $bID; ?>" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"       xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;" viewBox="0 0 <?= $width; ?> <?= $height; ?>"  >
<defs>
<symbol id="pin" viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>location on</title>
    <path d='M12 2c-3.87 0-7 3.13-7 7 0 5.25 7 13 7 13s7-7.75 7-13c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7zm0 9.5c-1.38 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5s1.12-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.12 2.5 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z'></path>
    <path d='M0 0h24v24h-24z' fill='none'></path>
</symbol>
</defs>

 <?php  
foreach($areas as $area) {
        $points = trim($area['mapdata']);
$url = $sec->sanitizeURL($area['linked_url']);
 ?>
<a class="arrow" id="pin" xlink:href="<?= $url; ?>" xlink:title="<?=  $title; ?>" <?= ($area['newWindow'] && !($area['forceDownload'] && $area['type'] == 'file') ? 'target="_blank"' : '')?>>
<g id="my-group">
<use xlink:href="#pin" x="" y="" width="30px" height="30px" />
<polygon points="<?= $points; ?>" fill="url(#img1)" filter="url(#sparklin)" opacity="1" />  
</g>
 </a> 

}
```

Displays all Icons on top left of map.. Not centered to each section.

UPDATES

---

Ok using the solution below: I created the following Function Above my Loop, but I hit an error with "Uncaught TypeError: poly.getBBox is not a function
    at myfunction (contacts:508)
    at contacts:566"

[code]

```
<script>
                        function myfunction(){
                        // the bounding box of the polygon
                            var BB = null;
                            var BB = poly.getBBox();
                            // the center of the polygon
                            var center = {x:BB.x + BB.width/2,
                                          y:BB.y + BB.height/2}
                            //the size of the symbol
                            var symbol = {w:30,h:30}
            // set the values for the x and y attributes of the symbol
        theUse.setAttributeNS(null, "x",center.x - symbol.w/2)
        theUse.setAttributeNS(null, "y",center.y - symbol.h)
                        };
                    </script>
//Code inside foreach

    <a class="arrow" xlink:href="<?= $url; ?>" xlink:title="<?=  $title; ?>">


                        <polygon id="poly" points="<?= $points; ?>" fill="none" opacity="1" />  
                        <use id="theUse" xlink:href="#pin" x="20" y="20" width="40" height="40" />

                        </a> 

                        <script>
                        myfunction();
                        </script>
[/code]
```

I believe this is an issue with the poly.getBBox();  Maybe this is todo with the ID of the poly being re-used? Do i need to add a count to the loop an increment for each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it would be using the bounding box of the polygon to find the center and then position the symbol relative to this center.

Next comes an example where I'm using a simplified version of your code. In this case the tip of the pin is in the center of the polygon-

Observation: in your code you have the `id="pin"` twice.

```js
// the bounding box of the polygon
let BB = poly.getBBox();
// the center of the polygon
let center = {x:BB.x + BB.width/2,
              y:BB.y + BB.height/2}
//the size of the symbol
let symbol = {w:30,h:30}
// set the values for the x and y attributes of the symbol
theUse.setAttributeNS(null, "x",center.x - symbol.w/2)
theUse.setAttributeNS(null, "y",center.y - symbol.h)
```

```css
svg{position:absolute;top:0;left:0; width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg id="svgmap" viewBox="0 0 100 100"  >
<defs>
<symbol id="pin" viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
    <path id="thePath" d='M12 2c-3.87 0-7 3.13-7 7 0 5.25 7 13 7 13s7-7.75 7-13c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7zm0 9.5c-1.38 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5s1.12-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.12 2.5 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z'></path>
    <path d='M0 0h24v24h-24z' fill='none'></path>
</symbol>
</defs>


<a class="arrow" id="a_pin" xlink:href="kk" xlink:title="title">
<g id="my-group">
  
<polygon id="poly" points="10,10 90,30 70,70 24,80" fill="gold"  opacity="1" />
<use id="theUse" xlink:href="#pin" x="20" y="20" width="30" height="30" />
  
</g>
</a> 
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

In the case you have several polygons you need to do it looping through the `<a class=arrow` elements like so:

```js
let aPins = svgmap.querySelectorAll(".arrow");

aPins.forEach(a => {
  let poly = a.querySelector("polygon");
  let pin = a.querySelector("use");
  centerPin(poly, pin);
});

function centerPin(poly, pin) {
  // the bounding box of the polygon
  let BB = poly.getBBox();
  // the center of the polygon
  let center = {
    x: BB.x + BB.width / 2,
    y: BB.y + BB.height / 2
  };
  //the size of the symbol
  let symbol = { w: 30, h: 30 };
  // set the values for the x and y attributes of the symbol
  pin.setAttributeNS(null, "x", center.x - symbol.w / 2);
  pin.setAttributeNS(null, "y", center.y - symbol.h);
}
```

```css
svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svgmap" viewBox="0 0 200 100"  >
<defs>
<symbol id="pin" viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
    <path id="thePath" d='M12 2c-3.87 0-7 3.13-7 7 0 5.25 7 13 7 13s7-7.75 7-13c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7zm0 9.5c-1.38 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5s1.12-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.12 2.5 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z'></path>
    <path d='M0 0h24v24h-24z' fill='none'></path>
</symbol>
</defs>


<a class="arrow" id="a_pin1" xlink:href="kk" xlink:title="title">
<g id="my-group">  
<polygon points="10,10 90,30 70,70 24,80" fill="gold"  opacity="1" />
<use  xlink:href="#pin" x="20" y="20" width="30" height="30" />  
</g>
</a> 
  
<a class="arrow" id="a_pin2" xlink:href="kk" xlink:title="title">
<g id="my-group">  
<polygon points="90,30 70,70 133,90 180,25" fill="skyBlue"   opacity="1" />
<use  xlink:href="#pin" x="20" y="20" width="30" height="30" />  
</g>
</a>  
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Ok Thanks , this kinda works. It runs the script and does the 1st in the Loop. But has errors due to 
Uncaught TypeError: poly.getBBox is not a function
    at myfunction (contacts:508)
    at contacts:566 
See My Updates Above

Comment: I suppose this happens in your code. In my code `poly` is the id of the polygon. If you have several polygons in your code you may need to get a reference to every polygon with something like `let poly =  document.querySelector(whatever`...

Comment: I've seen your update. Since you have several `<a class="arrow"` with a polygon inside you also have several polygons with the same `id="poly"`